# Managing cache synchronously in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, caching

I'm maintaining a cache in JavaScript using jquery in a global cache variable.

Whenever new information is received using AJAX it is added to the cache.

If it is not in the cache, I want to AJAX it from the server.

I want to implement a function to query on demand and to use it like so:

```
$("#label").html(GetName("user123"));
```

Where GetName() should be like:

```
function GetName(username) {
    if (Cache[username] != null) return Cache[username];
  else
    return QueryUsernameFromServer(username)
}
```

QueryUsernameFromServer() should be like:

```
function QueryUsernameFromServer (username) {
    return $.ajax(…);
}
```

However, $.ajax is async meaning that it cannot wait for a value (and thus cannot return it).

Using $.ajax in sync mode is highly not recommended (browser hangs and it doesn’t support JSONP), http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Using this, http://www.techfounder.net/2008/05/17/simple-javascript-cache/, approach requires a callback. However, creating a callback for each use is not desired.

Is there a good way to implement a “cache on demand” function in js and ajax without a dedicated callback for each use?

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to have the callback, because AJAX is...wait for it..."A"synchronous.

Just add a callback to your functions that query the cache. It's pretty simple:

```
function getName(username, callback){
  if(cache[username]){ 
     // cache hit, immediately invoke the callback
     callback(cache[username]); 
  }else{ 
    // assumes this query function updates the cache and invokes the
    // 2nd parameter when it completes
    queryUsernameFromServer(username, function(){
      // invoke the callback now
      callback(cache[username]);
    }); 
  }
}
```

And simply convert to an async style in your code:

Before:

```
var name = getName('jvenema');
```

After:

```
getName('jvenema', function(name){

});
```

Comment: +1 for good solution.  this is _exactly_ what I used for our data provider at work. I like having a data layer so that we can resuse it and update all the `ajax` code in one location (e.g. when jQuery overhauled their `ajax` namespace).

Answer (score 1):

If your using jQuery 1.5+ then you can just use deferreds.

```
function GetName(username) {
    if (Cache[username] != null) return $.when(Cache[username]);
  else
    return QueryUsernameFromServer(username)
}
```

And use deferreds as follows

```
GetName('jvenema').done(function(name) {

});
```